# Exporting GridView Data and Formatting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I have a aspxgridview. I want to be able to export it to excel with all of it's formatting without writing huge ammounts of excel formatting vb. 
I tried the aspxgridviewexporter function. This works fine for exporting the layout of the gridview. However some of my cells in the gridview are colored based on their values. I would like the coloured formatting to export to excel aswell. Is there any way in which i can acheive this?

Thanks, 
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible. To color the resulting report, you need to handle the exporter's [RenderBrick](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewExportASPxGridViewExporter_RenderBricktopic) event.  This topic contains the sample code which should allow you to achieve what you want.